# How to read a data from test file which is in different system drive using Batch command?

Tags: batch-file

How to read a data from test file which is in different system drive using Batch command?

```
for /f "delims=" %%x in (version.txt) do set ver=%%x
```

I have defined in C drive this text file but I have to use same variable in different location system drive script?

Comment: what is the problem with `for /f "usebackq delims=" %%x in ("F:\version.txt") do set ver=%%x`  ?

Comment: there is an environment variable named `%SystemDrive%`...

Comment: Thanks a lot Mate....It works Highly Appriciated your quick help..